# How to use Optional in a if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, jpa, option-type

I have a many to many table of orders. For every order id there can be a lot of product ids. When I fetch the data from db I'm trying to get all the products for every order respectively in a view object. The idea was to check if the order id of the last element in LinkedList (the list I'm trying to return with the method) is the same as the order id of the next element that I am trying to write into the list. If the order is the same I add another product to that order, if it isn't I make a new order with its product.

```
public List<OrderVO> getOrders(int id) {

    List<Orders> orders = orderRepository.findByUserId(id);
    List<OrderProduct> orderProduct = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Orders o : orders) orderProduct = orderProductRepository.findByOrderId(o.getId());

    LinkedList<OrderVO> orderz = new LinkedList<>();

    for (OrderProduct op : orderProduct) {

        OrderVO order = new OrderVO(Long.valueOf(op.getOrders().getId()));

        Optional<Product> pResponse = productRepository.findById(op.getProduct().getId());
        Product p = pResponse.get();
        ProductVO pVO = new ProductVO(p.getId(), p.getName(), op.getAmountOfOrderedProduct());

        if (orderz.peekLast().getId() == order.getId()) {
            OrderVO o = orderz.getLast();
            o.getOrderProducts().add(pVO);
            orderz.addLast(o);
        } else {
            order.getOrderProducts().add(pVO);
            orderz.addLast(order);
        }
    }
    return orderz;
}
```

The problem is that `orderz.peekLast().getId()` at first iteration always throws a Null Pointer Exception. So i tried to check if its null gracefully with a optional like so:

```
  Optional<LinkedList<OrderVO>> orderz = Optional.ofNullable(new LinkedList<>());
                          .
                          .
                          .

            if (orderz.ifPresent(orderVOS -> orderz.get().peekLast().getId()) == order.getId()) {
                OrderVO o = orderz.get().getLast();
                o.getOrderProducts().add(pVO);
                orderz.get().addLast(o);
            } else {
                order.getOrderProducts().add(pVO);
                orderz.get().addLast(order);
            }
```

Though it seems that the `orderz.ifPresent(orderVOS -> orderz.get().peekLast().getId())` defualt value is void so i can't compare it with an int.
Ironically for this one, I try to keep my code as clean as possible. Any other suggestions of how to tide up this snippet of code would be appreciated.

Comment: Just do a null check `if(val == null)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to have read the Java API because then you might have seen that `ifPresent` is used to conditionally execute code given to `ifPresent` if the `Optional` is present. What you are searching for is something similar to

```
if (orderz.peekLast() == null || orderz.peekLast().getId() != order.getId()) {
    order.getOrderProducts().add(pVO);
    orderz.addLast(order);
} else {
    OrderVO o = orderz.getLast();
    o.getOrderProducts().add(pVO);
    orderz.addLast(o);
}
```

Comment: Or cleaner, `if(orderz.isEmpty() || orderz.peekLast().getId() != order.getId()) ...`. But some attention should be paid to the fact that `getLast()` does not remove the element, so there's no need for a subsequent `orderz.addLast(o)`, unless the element truly ought to be repeated. Also, the `Long.valueOf(op.getOrders().getId())` suggests that the id could be `Long` rather than `long`, in which case it must be compared using `equals` rather than `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Your orderz linkedlist is empty on first iteration.
That's why you get a NullPointerException.